# How can I add 2 autonumber columns in MS Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am coding a webpage with ASP .NET C#

I need to add 2 autonumber fields in MS Access but it don't let me do it. I did like this:

```
field size = replication ID
Sequential= yes, without replication
```

But my column (it calls `unique_id`) had a value like this `={BBEB19C8-9C6D-4A1D-B966-A409A849D417}`. As a result, I want to add a second autonumber field to my MS Access database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

A "replication ID" is a GUID.  It has to be in order for any form of replication to work.

Also, you can't have 2 auto number columns in the same table.  It's kind of pointless.

Just to give an idea on why there's no reason to do this, consider the following hypothetical table definition.

**Cars**
*id*: autonumber
*otherid*: autonumber
*name*: varchar(100)

If you insert a record with the name value of "ford" you'll have a record that looks like:
1, 1, ford

When you insert a second record, for chevy, it will look like:
2, 2, chevy

Note how both id fields have the same value?

Now, let's say you modified your table definition to seed the "otherid" starting at value 100.  Doing the same inserts would yield:

1, 101, ford
2, 102, chevy

The second field just takes up space while providing nothing in return because the column can easily be computed by adding 100 to the id key.

I'm guessing that you are missing something fundamental here.  If you provide details on what you are trying to accomplish and why you think you need 2 auto number fields I'm pretty certain the community can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: UPPS..
Okey, do you have an idea about this topic? Because I need second autonumber field or something like that.

Comment: @dmrc1143: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes sir, I wanna do that you write second one. "1, 101, ford
2, 102, chevy" I need something like that. How can I do..?

Comment: The GUID fields on which Jet Replication depends are added automatically -- you don't have to create them. And those can exist in a table with an Autonumber field, so somehow Replication overcomes the restriction on one Autonumber per table (this was news to me -- I'd never noticed it before, despite having worked with Jet Replication extensively for over 10 years). But replicating your data is not a solution to the problem!